# optional matching of multiple regex subpattern

Tags: javascript, regex, coffeescript

I have a regex problem which bugs me and have no clue how to solve it.

I have an input field with a text and I like to extract certain values out of it. 
I would like to extract a title, description, a price and a special price.

Examples for the input:

- everything what is plain text is concerned as title.
- everything within within hashes (#description goes here#) is considered the description.
- $23.49 is considered as price and %$19.99 would match the special price.

The CoffeeScript pattern I'm using:

```
 pattern = ///
  ([^$]+)
  (#(.+?)#+)
  ([\$]\d+\. \d+)
  ([\%\$]\d+\. \d+)
  ///
  params = [title,description,oldPrice,newPrice]=input_txt.match(pattern)[1..4]
```

It does not work. It should work if I enter all values in the given sequence and I also have to provide a the asked substring.

What I would like to have is the ability to extract the sequments if the are provided (so optional) and no matter of the sequence... 
How can I extract optional sequences of an string...
EDIT///
I provide some examples

**exmp1:**

```
Kindle #Amazon's ebook reader# $79.00
```

this should be extracted as

```
title:Kindle 
description: Amazon's ebook reader 
oldPrice:$79.00
```

**exmp2:**

```
Nike Sneaker's $109.00 %$89.00
```

this should be extracted as

```
title:Nikes Sneaker's 
oldPrice:$109.00 
newPrice:$89.00
```

**exmp3:**

```
$100.00 Just dance 3 #for XBox#
```

this should be extracted to

```
title: Just dance 3 
description: for XBox 
oldPrice:$100.00
```

Any help would be great ...

Comment: Please provide several examples of the strings you're trying to parse.  If you want to match things in any order, you will have to use multiple different regexes.

Comment: I provided some example strings...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The nature of regular grammars makes it hard to solve your problem. As a work around the simplest solution would be to just execute your regex 4 times:

1. Match /#(.+?)#+/ and remove the result string (string replace) from the original
2. Match /[\%\$]\d+. \d+/ and remove the result string from the original
3. Match /[\$]\d+. \d+/ and... you get the pattern
4. Now what remains in the original is the the title.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code that looks for a removes each separate piece of the matches:

```
function extractParts(str) {
    var parts = {};

    function removePiece(re) {
        var result;
        var matches = str.match(re);
        if (matches) {
            result = matches[1];
            str = str.replace(re, "");
        }
        return(result);
    }

    // find and remove each piece we're looking for
    parts.description = removePiece(/#([^#]+)#/);        // #text#
    parts.oldPrice = removePiece(/[^%](\$\d+\.\d+)/);    // $4.56
    parts.newPrice = removePiece(/%(\$\d+\.\d+)/);       // %$3.78
    // fix up whitespace
    parts.title = str.replace(/\s+/g, " ").replace(/^\s+/, "").replace(/\s+$/, "");
    return(parts);
}

var pieces = extractParts("Kindle #Amazon's ebook reader# $79.00");
```

And, you can see a demo in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/d8NNr/.